# Whitespace in bottom of my Flutter App when I run on emulator

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, responsive-design, scaffold

When I launch my app with the smartphone emulator I get a white space at the bottom :

[image]

I tried to add this line in my Scaffold but doesn't seems to work :

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the white space is coming from your device navigation bar.

Try to set     `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode()` to manually set the ui overlays you want.

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
    SystemUiMode.manual,
    overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top],
  );

  runApp(AppWidget());
}
```

Or set `overlays: [],` for fullscreen

Documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setEnabledSystemUIMode.html

Comment: Thanks, overlays: [] works well for me, overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top] give another kind of white space